# Get the signed/unsigned variant of an integer template parameter without explicit traits

Tags: c++, templates, unsigned, traits, partial-specialization

I am looking to define a template class whose template parameter will always be an integer type. The class will contain two members, one of type `T`, and the other as the unsigned variant of type `T` -- i.e. if `T == int`, then `T_Unsigned == unsigned int`. My first instinct was to do this:

```
template <typename T> class Range {
    typedef unsigned T T_Unsigned; // does not compile
public:
    Range(T min, T_Unsigned range);
private:
    T m_min;
    T_Unsigned m_range;
};
```

But it doesn't work. I then thought about using partial template specialization, like so:

```
template <typename T> struct UnsignedType {}; // deliberately empty
template <> struct UnsignedType<int> {
    typedef unsigned int Type;
};

template <typename T> class Range {
    typedef UnsignedType<T>::Type T_Unsigned;
    /* ... */
};
```

This works, so long as you partially specialize `UnsignedType` for *every* integer type. It's a little bit of additional copy-paste work (slash judicious use of macros), but serviceable.

However, I'm now curious - is there another way of determining the signed-ness of an integer type, and/or using the unsigned variant of a type, without having to manually define a Traits class per-type? Or is this the only way to do it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is in `<type_traits>`

For determining the signed-ness of a type use `std::is_signed` and `std::is_unsigned`.

For adding/removing signed-ness, there is `std::make_signed` and `std::make_unsigned`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't or don't want to depend on TR1/C++0x features, [Boost.TypeTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html) also offers you `make_unsigned<>` et al.

Comment: +1 - as it happens I'm using Visual Studio 2005 which doesn't support `<type_traits>` - so having an alternative is handy. I still accepted `<type_traits>` as the answer as it's part of the Standard Library.

Comment: @Blair: Careful, thats actually *"will be part of"* - its part of the next standard that is not out yet.