# Making function template parameter unsigned in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

In a template function that looks like this:

```
template<typename T> constexpr T foo(T a, T b) { return /*recursive call*/; }
```

I am getting a warning about comparing signed vs unsigned (due to comparing against `sizeof`) which I'd like to eliminate.

Conceptually, one would need something like this:

```
template<typename T> constexpr T foo(T a, unsigned T b) { ... }
    or
template<typename T> constexpr T foo(T a, std::make_unsigned<T>::type b) { ... }
```

Unluckily, the first version is not valid C++, and the second version breaks the build because T is not a qualified type when the compiler sees `make_unsigned`.

Is there is a solution for this that actually works?

(NB: Somehow related to / almost same as [Get the signed/unsigned variant of an integer template parameter without explicit traits](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2824431/572743), though function rather than class (so no typedefs), traits or any feature of C++11 explicitly welcome, and working solution (i.e. *not* `make_unsigned<T>`) preferred.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You forgot a 'typename'

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T foo(T a, typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type b) { ... }
```

In C++14 you should be able to write

```
template<typename T>
constexpr T foo(T a, std::make_unsigned_t<T> b) { ... }
```

Or you can implement this yourself in C++11:

```
template<typename T>
using make_unsigned_t = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue for C++03. I want two templates: one for `template <class unsigned T, class unsigned U>` and class `template <class signed T, class signed U>`. I need to test if a cast can be made from `T` to `U`. Is there a solution in the C++03 world? (Does this warrant a new question)?

Comment: @jww yeah, I'd say that should be its own question.